# Android device stops replying to ping after some time

Tags: android, android-source, android-networking

I'm developing a kiosk mode application on Android 4.4

My device has a 3G SIM card with static (fixed) public IP. Therefore I can ping my Android device from the Internet.

After some days (or hours sometimes) I cannot ping the device anymore. Why does the device stops listening on the network interface? The device is still powered of course. If I switch the device to plane mode and then disable plane mode it works back again but I don't won't to activate plane mode, I want the device to be listening 24/7.

I can't develop a server service because of these disconnections. anyway I can debug?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed rare to have a static IP on a mobile wireless data network.

Just a theory: it may be possible there is some form of optimiser system on the cell network, that does not account for static ip's, that drops connections if it has not heard from the device for X period of time.

Thus, you could try adding a small piece of code that pings from your phone or performs a simple http-get every hour.  If that does stop the dropouts, then you could progressively widen that time window until you find the threshold.

Comment: Thank you for your clue. Oh I'm sorry I forgot to mention that data is very expensive with such SIM cards so I cannot afford to spend kB of data every day...

Comment: Understand the data cost.  You would need very minimal data for just a ping. 
e.g a ``ping -s 1 www.google.com`` will ping google with 29 byte total packet (20 bytes IP header + 8 bytes ICMP header 1 byte data).    Which by a rough cacluation: pinging once per hour, it would take about 3.9 years to use just one megabyte.  Maybe half that to 2 years to allow for reply packet...

Comment: But for testing, I would stll reccomend a quick TCP HTTP-GET. Reason being, I know they sometimes do not "count" ICMP.  I have a colleuge who wrote his own transfer program, funnelling all data in ICMP instead of TCP, because he ICMP didn't count towards his mobile data allowance...